# Using list of strings to manipulate pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a very long list of strings. These strings are those columns I would like to keep from a dataframe. However, there are a couple of strings in this list that don't match a column header, instead it matches an operation between two or more column headers I would like to performs.

Example:

```
   df =  @A @B @C @D @E @F
         1   2  3  4  5  6
         9   8  7  6  5  4
         1   3  5  7  9  11

list = ["@A", "@C", "@D / @F"]
```

I would like this to output:

```
@A @C @D/@F
1   3  0.667
9   7  1.5
1   5  0.63
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out what to do. 
To make things a bit more complicated, sometimes in my list you might see a simple division like in my example, sometimes you might see something more complicated like `"(C + D) / (A + F)"`. How would I do this??

I honestly can't figure out where to start. I thought I could just do something like df[list] and pandas would just "know" what to do, but I think I might be asking a bit too much!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: 
After trying to use the eval() method, I've bumped into another issue. I didn't though this could be a problem, but most of my strings begin with the character "@" which throws up an error when passed into the eval function. I'll do some googling on how to work around this, but any additional help is also welcome.

Edit 2:

I figured out a work around for the @ issue. I simply used the replace() method.

```
lst = [word.replace("@", "") for word in lst]
```

Then, I do the same this for all of my columns as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

***note**: never use `list` as a listname, its a reserved word in Python. I changed it to `lst`*

```
lst = ["A", "C", "D / F"]

df = pd.DataFrame(df.eval(lst).T, columns=lst)
```

**Output**

```
   A  C     D / F
0  1  3  0.666667
1  9  7       1.5
2  1  5  0.636364
```

---

If we extend your `lst` with more complex calculation, this method still holds:

```
lst = ["A", "C", "D / F", "(C + D) / (A + F)"]

df = pd.DataFrame(df.eval(lst).T, columns=lst)
```

**Output**

```
   A  C     D / F (C + D) / (A + F)
0  1  3  0.666667                 1
1  9  7       1.5                 1
2  1  5  0.636364                 1
```

Comment: This is even simpler. Thank you. One issue I'm facing now though is that the first character in most of the strings with my lst is the character "@". This is making python quite angry.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly @JrAnalyst

Comment: I ended up using your solution. However, I don't put ".T" at the end. And instead of calling the whole list in eval() and columns=, I instead loop through my list with an index. I seem to be getting the right results though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, what would be necessary is to write a simple parser to make the operation. But Python gives a method that could solve your problem: `eval()`.
From this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826500/python-eval-function-with-numpy-arrays-via-string-input-with-dictionaries), we can deduce that:

```
>>> var = {'a':np.array([1,2,2]),'b':np.array([2,1,3]),'c':np.array([3])}
>>> formula = '2*a*(b/c)**2'
>>> eval(formula, var)
array([ 0.8889,  0.4444,  4.    ])
```

So, if you defined at first every column inside a well-formed dict, it should work as expected.

For example:

```
var = {'A': df[0], 'B':df[1], ...}
eval(list[0], var)
```

Be careful when you are using `eval()` though. It can be quite [dangerous](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) if you are not the one giving the variable to the method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is fantastic. I didn't know this method existed. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Also, thank you for the link to that other Q&A.