# I need a program to take mathematical expression as input and evaluate its value in a range

Tags: numpy, eval

```
xvals = linspace(a, b, 1001)
expr = //string taken as input
yvals=list()
for x in xvals:
    y=eval(expr)
    yvals.append(y)
plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
```

This works fine for any polynomial function But gives error in case of sin(x) or log(x)
: name 'sin(x)' is not defined
How to resolve this?

Comment: What are your inports?  Is `linspace` from `numpy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python eval function with numpy arrays via string input with dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826500/python-eval-function-with-numpy-arrays-via-string-input-with-dictionaries)
Also you could have a look at sympy for advanced symbolic calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Importing the `math` module should work:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

xvals = np.linspace(0, pi, 5 )
expr = "sin(x)"
yvals=list()
for x in xvals:
    y=eval(expr)
    yvals.append(y)

print(yvals)
#[0.0, 0.7071067811865475, 1.0, 0.7071067811865476, 1.2246467991473532e-16]
```

Keep in mind you can use `eval` with any function, e.g.:

```
my_func = lambda x: x/3 + 1
eval("my_func(9)")
#4.0
```

So, importing all functions from `math` solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't import math librabry.It works now