# Python eval() fails to regonize numpy and math symbols if used together with a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, evaluation, built-in

I have the following formula that I would like to evaluate:

```
import math
import numpy as np
formula  = 'np.e**x + math.erf(x) + np.pi  +  math.erf(u)'
```

I can easily then evaluate the formula for given float values of x and u and eval() recognizes math.erf, np.pi and np.e. For example:

```
x=1.0; u=0.3; eval(formula)
```

yields 7.03. But,  I want x and u to be arrays. I tried to use eval with a dictionary following [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826500/python-eval-function-with-numpy-arrays-via-string-input-with-dictionaries):

```
var = {'x':np.array([1,1]),'u':np.array([0.1,0.2])}
eval(formula, var)
```

which yields error messages, 'np' and 'math' are not defined, which was **not** the case above when eval was used without a dict. The same error messages are also obtained when 'x' and 'u' are set to floats instead of array with the *var* dictionary. Also, there are no problems if the dictionary is used with a 'formula' without np. and math., e.g. "

```
formula = 'x + u'.
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I evaluate formula containing np.e, math.erf, etc., when x and u are arrays?

P.S. I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: Pass your dictionary as the locals, not globals. `eval(formula, locals=var)`

Comment: var = {'x': np.array([1,1]), 'u': np.array([0.1,0.2]), 'np': np, 'math': math}
result = eval(formula, var), this should help

Comment: Beside the point, but the `math` module doesn't operate on arrays, only scalar real numbers.

Comment: ^ numpy doesn't have an `erf`, but [scipy does](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `var` as *globals* to [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) means the global names `np` and `math` are not available to the expression (`formula`). Simply pass `var` as *locals* instead.

```
var = {'x': 1.0, 'u': 0.3}
eval(formula, None, var)  # -> 7.031202034457681
```

*Note that this code doesn't work with arrays since the `math` module only works on scalars.*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier with named arguments, so you don't have to specify `None` as the globals?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but `eval()` doesn't take any keyword arguments. Although, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) say it does. Looks like a documentation bug.

Comment: Looks like a version issue. `help(eval)` in 3.9 shows `eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)`. It changed to `eval(expression, /, globals=None, locals=None)` in 3.11.

Comment: @Barmar `help(eval)` in 3.11 still shows `eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)`. (I installed it just to check this, lol.) The problem is that the docs don't agree with `help()`. I opened [a bug about it](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100546).

Comment: Thanks, @wjandrea, this solved the problem (at least in 3.8). With scipy's erf, can also do arrays.